# Show one post per author and limit query to 8 posts

Tags: wp-query, author, array, recent-posts

I want to show 8 recent products from multiple authors on the frontpage.
Need to show 1 recent product per author.

Currently i'm using basic wp query to show recent 8 products.

```
$args = array (
'post_type'              => array( 'product' ),
'posts_per_page'         => '8',
'order'                  => 'DESC',
'orderby'                => 'date',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What if there's more or less than 8 authors?

Comment: There is more than 100 authors on the site. I need to display only latest 8 products on the frontpage. 1 latest product per author.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you tried the current answer? If that doesn't work for you comment on it and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you can achieve this effect by grouping the query by author ID, which will require a filter([mostly cribbed from the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_groupby)):

```
function my_posts_groupby($groupby) {
    global $wpdb;
    $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author";
    return $groupby;
}
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'my_posts_groupby' );
```

If you have less than 8 authors, however, this won't work. (You will get a number of results equal to your number of authors.) If that is the case you will need much more complicated logic and a much more complicated code.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could work. However how do I get this to apply just to my query above? Wouldn't this affect all queries?

Comment: `remove_filter()` after your query runs.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone coming to this years after the fact and would like the code in full, rather than having to piece this together from comments and the accepted answer, here you go!

**Declare the function that limits the post results to 1 per author**. For me, this was in functions.php:

```
function one_per_author($groupby) {
    global $wpdb;
    $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author";
    return $groupby;
}
```

Do NOT follow this with `apply_filter` as per the accepted answer - this would then apply to all loops.

**Next run the loop you would like to filter**, and call the `apply` and `remove` filters directly before and after it:

```
$args = array (
'post_type'              => array( 'product' ),
'posts_per_page'         => '8',
'order'                  => 'DESC',
'orderby'                => 'date',
);

add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'one_per_author' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
      // Do loop stuff
   endwhile;
endif;
remove_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'one_per_author' );
```