# WP query posts BUT show the most recent and one per author

Tags: php, functions, wp-query

I want to display 12 articles first goes the latest BUT i want to show only one post per user. For example if user A wrote 2 artticles today i want to display only the latest of his articles.

Here is the query i use

```
<?php
                
        //the array 1
                $args = array(
                /*'posts_per_page' => 12, /* how many post you need to display */
                'offset' => 0,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'blog', /* your post type name */
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                
            );

            $query1 = new WP_Query($args);           
        ?>
```

So my code now after the comments is like this

```
<?php
  $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 12, /* how many post you need to display */
'offset' => 0,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'post_type' => 'blog', /* your post type name */
'group_by'  => 'date',
'post_status' => 'publish',    
  );
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'one_per_author' );
 $query1 = new WP_Query($args);           
        ?>
```

but i still dont get the latest and some authors are 2 times

Comment: It's just my guess, but I think you need to group your query by author using add_filter and remove_filter after your query (because it will affect on every query on your site). I'm far from PC, but you may find a good example here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209089/show-one-post-per-author-and-limit-query-to-8-posts

Comment: and how i add the filter to the query?

Comment: Query arguments will not change, add this function for filter in your functions.php `function one_per_author($groupby) {
    global $wpdb;
    $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author";
    return $groupby;
}` , then, before your you call WP_Query, add this function as a filter `add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'one_per_author' );` . And then, after WP_Query loop, remove this filter by `remove_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'one_per_author' );` Check the link I attached earlier, second answer)

Comment: i updated the code but still i cant see the latest post (the one i made right now) and i see some authors 2 times

Comment: I just checked this code on my WP installation. It really groups posts by author and shows only 1 post per author. But groupby returns the oldest post of this author instead of the latest. According to raw SQL queries in this query should be also MAX(date) as returning field, but wp_query doesn't allow to set custom field to return. If no one will give a more native anwer to your question, I guess you may achieve your goal with wpdb class and own SQL query.

Comment: can you send me the code you added? i made it in an other way. I store the author ID in a variable and i check it everytime with the new author.